# How to select multiple photos from gallery and retrieve in a grid view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, converters, gif

I asked a question yesterday about how to select multiple photos from gallery at once. Someone asked me to add the code

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

When I did it did work with Photos, not Gallery, gallery you still can't pick more than one photo, it's when you click on photos. Problem is, even in photos when you select the multiple photos and say ok, it doesn't retrieve them it says unfortunately the app has stopped and closes the app. My app is a gif creator using multiple photos from gallery or camera.

My Code: 
Intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/* video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
```

Whole activity main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * this is the destination of the new GIF file, it will be saved directly in the SD card
 * (internal storage) in a file named "test.gif"
 */
private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/sdcard/test.gif";
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
private boolean zoomOut = false;
private Button btnSelect;
private LinearLayout root;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

    ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (root.getChildCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(IMAGE_PATH);
                outStream.write(generateGIF());
                outStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "GIF saved to " + IMAGE_PATH, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (outStream != null) {
                    try {
                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/* video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++)
    {
        Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
    }

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 800, 150, true);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageView ivImage = new ImageView(this);
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(0xFF00FF00); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
    gd.setCornerRadius(5);
    gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);

    ivImage.setBackground(gd);


// the following code causes a crash "NullPointerException" :

//        Point point = null; // --> the reason for the crash
//        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
//        int width = point.x;
//        int height = point.y;
//
//        ivImage.setMinimumWidth(width);
//        ivImage.setMinimumHeight(height);
//
//        ivImage.setMaxWidth(width);
//        ivImage.setMaxHeight(height);
//        ivImage.getLayoutParams().width = 20; // --> another crash happens here
//        ivImage.getLayoutParams().height = 20;


    ivImage.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    root.addView(ivImage);

//        setContentView(root);
//        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final ImageView ivImage = new ImageView(this);
    ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (zoomOut) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NORMAL SIZE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ivImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ivImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                zoomOut = false;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FULLSCREEN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ivImage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                ivImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                zoomOut = true;
            }
        }
    });
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    ivImage.setMinimumWidth(width);
    ivImage.setMinimumHeight(height);

    ivImage.setMaxWidth(width);
    ivImage.setMaxHeight(height);
    ivImage.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            1000,
            1000));
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    root.addView(ivImage);
    setContentView(root);
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

}

private byte[] generateGIF() {

    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

    View v;
    ImageView iv;
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
        v = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            iv = (ImageView) v;
            bitmaps.add(((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

}
```

Comment: use this library; its very good for multiple image selection; https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: could you please help me out configuring this library or adding it as I don't know? @DJphy

Comment: try to go through this activity; https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/com/beanie/imagechooserapp/ImageChooserActivity.java

Comment: should I paste that in my main activity and where?

Comment: beginner in android ??

Comment: yes :/ and it's a project I have to turn in soon